# Homomorphism problem gone wrong

Tags: group-theory, proof-verification, fake-proofs, abstract-algebra

Okay, so I'm working on a homework problem in abstract algebra, and I have found the solution already, what I want to know is why my initial line of reasoning didn't work - i..e, what have I done or assumed that I am not allowed to do.

The problem is as follows. Suppose that $\phi: Z_{50} \rightarrow Z_{15}$ is a homomorphism of groups, such that $\phi (7)=6$ Determine $\phi (x)$ for every $x \in Z_{50}$. Here was my line of reasoning.

$ \phi (7)=6 \implies [\phi (7)]^2=6^2  \implies \phi(49)=6$ by the properties of a homomorphism (which I'm reading from Galian, 8th ed. page 210, in case that matters). But $49 \equiv -1  \pmod{50}$, so that $\phi(-1)=6$. But now we can use the same property as before to note that $[\phi(-1)]^2 = \phi(1)=6.$ which would imply that $\phi (x) = 6x$.

But something in this line of reasoning is wrong, because $7\times 6$ is 42, which is not $6 \bmod 15$. It's $12$.

Now, I already know that the right definition for $\phi$ is that $\phi (x)= 3x$, as $3$ is the smallest integer $a$ so that $7a\equiv 6 \pmod{15}$, what I don't know and can't figure out, is why my analysis is wrong the first time.

Comment: Homomorphisms of groups, rings or what?

Comment: Oh! Sorry. I thought that might be clear. Homormorphism of groups.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Because the operation in $\mathbb{Z}_{50}$ is supposed to be the sum and not the product… it is not a *ring homomorphism*, but just a group homomorphism and those are groups with respect to the sum!
A group homomorphism preserves only an operation and in this case it is the sum, not the product!

Comment: Oh I see. I have mixed up the operation in the group. Thanks for that!

Answer (score 3):

$Z_{50}$ and $Z_6$ are addictive groups, so it's not true that $\phi (7)=6 \implies [\phi (7)]^2=6^2  \implies \phi(49)=6$